# How to run another process continuously after dismiss the modal

Tags: swift, swiftui

I want to run another process continuously after dismiss the modal.

In the following code, the modal is not dismissed and only the subsequent processing is performed.

How can I do that?

I used NotificationCenter and callbacks, all with the same result.

```
struct HomeView: View {
    @State private var modalPresented: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: {}) {
                Text("setting")
            }.sheet(isPresented: self.$modalPresented) {
                SettingView(onDismiss: {
                    self.modalPresented = false
                })
            }
        }
    }
}

struct SettingView: View {
    var onDismiss: () -> ()
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode: Binding<PresentationMode>

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: {
                self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                // The following is the logout function.
                logout()
            }) {
                Text("logout")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

do you mean like so?

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var modalPresented: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: {
                self.modalPresented.toggle()
            }) {
                Text("setting")
                }
            .sheet(isPresented: self.$modalPresented) {
                SettingView()
//                    .onDismiss: {
//                        self.modalPresented = false
//                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct SettingView: View {

    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode: Binding<PresentationMode>

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: {
                self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                print("logout")
            }) {
                Text("logout")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much.
It is a question.
Is there only one change?
Is only the part where "onDismiss" is commented out?

Comment: I'm sorry....
Added "toggle" code, but modal was not dismissed.